# How can I load a partially trained model in PyTorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

Let's suppose that the model I'm loading has 4 layers (layer0, layer1, layer2, layer3) for simplicity. If I only wanted that model to be pretrained for say layer0 and layer1, but have randomly initialized parameters for layer2 and layer3, how would I be able to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by freezing the layers you want it not to change(pretrained) and leave the other unfreezed(they will continue to train)

```
model_ft = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
ct = 0
for child in model_ft.children():
    ct += 1
    if ct < 7:
        for param in child.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False
```

This freezes layers 1-6 in the total 10 layers of Resnet50.

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself clearly. I don't want to freeze the layers. I want to retrain them using random initialization. So I don't want the pretrained weights there at start of training is what I'm saying. Not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: Oh i see. you can use `child.reset_parameters()` inside the if statement instead of freezing the layer of course after changing the condition. I'm not sure if it's going to work so tell me the result.